# Swift 3 How to display a confirmation screen based on MFMailComposeResult email screen

Tags: swift, email, segue

I'm building an app that constructs an email and presents it in a MFMailComposeViewController for the user to send.  When the user sends or cancels it I want the app to respond with an appropriate confirmation screen message.

I'm able to compose the email, dismiss the compose screen, and I have a named segue in IB from the pre-compose view to the confirmation view.  But I cannot get that segue to execute.

So, how can I update text message in the segue destination and then segue to it.

Because I'm trying to learn Swift I'm very interested in understanding how the code works, not just getting code that works.  So I really do appreciate any help.

The workflow starts with the user snapping a photo from the app:

```
    func snapPhoto(){

    if let cameraConnection = sessionOutput.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) {

        sessionOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: cameraConnection, completionHandler: { buffer, error in

            let myMessage   = self.buildEmail()
            let myJpg       = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(buffer)
            let mapSnap     = (self.myMap == nil) ? nil : UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.myMap!)

            let mail        = self.setupMail(to: myMessage.to, subject: myMessage.subject, body: myMessage.body, myJpg: myJpg!, mapSnap: mapSnap)

            self.presentMailComposer(mail: mail)

        }) // close completionHandler

    } // close if let cameraConnection

} // close func snapPhoto
```

Which assembles all of the email message content and passes it to:

```
    func presentMailComposer(mail : MFMailComposeViewController) {

    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {

        self.present(mail, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else {

        let sendMailErrorAlert = UIAlertController.init(title: "Uh oh!", message: "Unable to send email.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        self.present(sendMailErrorAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } // close if

} // close presentEmailComposer
```

And then this fires when the user taps "Send" of "Cancel"

```
public func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {

    switch result.rawValue {

    case MFMailComposeResult.cancelled.rawValue:

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "afterEmail", sender: self)
        print("Mail cancelled")

    case MFMailComposeResult.saved.rawValue:

        print("Mail saved")

    case MFMailComposeResult.sent.rawValue:

        print("Mail sent")

    case MFMailComposeResult.failed.rawValue:

        print("Mail sent failure: %@", [error!.localizedDescription])

    default:

        break

    }

    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

} // close mailCompose
```

And this is where I find myself stumped.  I can access MFMailComposeResult, and it is correct, but I cannot figure out how to present the confirmation view so it is available as the compose view slides away.

Comment: You need to add some code for us to understand what you've tried. I think should check out [`mailComposeDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/messageui/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller/1616890-mailcomposedelegate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your view controller the MFMailComposeViewController  delegate and override the method didFinishWith result and switch MFMailComposeResult value inside the completion handler of the dismiss method :

```
func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
    controller.dismiss(animated: true) { 
        // do whatever you need to do after dismissing the mail window
        switch result {
            case .cancelled: print("cancelled")
            case .saved:     print("saved")
            case .sent:
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Mail Composer", message: "Mail was successfully sent", preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .default, handler: nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true)
            case .failed:    print("failed")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Leo, thanks.  I got this far, but I cannot figure out how to present the confirmation view once the compose view closes.

Comment: So put the alert code inside of the controller.alert completion handler, which is inside of the of the mailComposeController completion handler?  I had not considered nesting completion handlers.  Thanks!

Comment: The alert works perfectly!  However I would like to present a whole new view for a much richer confirmation.  This seems like something conceptually different from popping an alert.

Comment: You can do whatever you want. Just present the view controller of your choice there

Comment: Is presenting a new view controller in this situation better handled entirely in code, or though a segue defined in IB, or does it not matter?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to present an alert before the controller is dismissed? Try this one:

```
func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {


    switch result {
    case .cancelled:

        let alertController = UIAlertController.init(title: "Cancelled", message: "Some message", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (alertAction) in
            controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))
        controller.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    case .sent:

        let alertController = UIAlertController.init(title: "Sent", message: "Some message", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (alertAction) in
            controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))
        controller.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: OPs comment "I cannot figure out how to present the confirmation view once the compose view closes"

Comment: @LeoDabus For this comment your answer is right solution.

Comment: Yes, this works but it fires before that compose view closes.  I'm looking for after.