# How to get the recipient email from MFMailComposeViewController after the email is sent

Tags: ios, swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

SWIFT (4 or above).

I have one action (button) that triggers a MailViewController (`let mc: MFMailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()`) at that point I only have the title and body of the message I want to send, **but not the recipient**.

I have setup mailComposeController (see below)

```
extension MyViewController: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
        switch result {
        case .cancelled:
            print("Mail cancelled")
        case .saved:
            print("Mail saved")
        case .sent:
            print("Mail sent to")
        case .failed:
            self.showAlert(title: "Error", message: "Mail was not send due to the following error:\n \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        default:
            break
        }
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

And I would like to save the recipient when the mail is sent (`.sent`) so that the user can check who he already emailed or not.

Is there a way to recover the recipient email address from `mailComposeController` ?

Comment: You can't. It is a potential privacy violation.

Comment: potential... Well, looks like I will have to add a UIView before calling it and... voilà

Comment: Not related to your question but your switch statement should be located inside the dismiss method completion handler instead of passing nil. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43432239/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus not sure. If the email is incorrect the user may want to correct it and resend the email.

Comment: Check the linked question. I am pretty sure you need to move it there.