# MFMailComposerViewController not geting to didFinishWithResult

Tags: swift

I have a created a very simple project that uses MFMailComposeViewController that gets into the Mail and the send button does the send successfully, but I am not getting to the function didFinishWithResult

I have tried with and without a UINavigationController
I have tried self.dismiss as well as controller.dismiss
putting a break point inside the didFinishWithResult. I never get there

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

    @IBAction func butTestMailTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if !MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Alert", message: "Mail Server not available", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "ok", otherButtonTitles: "")
            alert.show()
            return
        }

        let composeVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        composeVC.mailComposeDelegate = self

        // Configure the fields of the interface.
        composeVC.setToRecipients(["xxx@xx.xx.xx"])

        // Present the view controller modally.
        self.present(composeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)



    }

       func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController!, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError!) {
            // Check the result or perform other tasks.

            // Dismiss the mail compose view controller.
           controller.dismiss(animated: true,completion: nil)
        }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43432239/2303865

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need latest update in [Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messageui/mfmailcomposeviewcontrollerdelegate/1616880-mailcomposecontroller)

```
func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, 
                  didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, 
                          error: Error?) { }
```

Comment: Thankyou, such a subtle change, wish Apple would update the whole of there documentation, text changed example code not changed